# Make AR targeted object always stand upright AND rotate around worldUp vector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

The title might be a bit confusing. I have a simple Vuforia project in Unity where I render a few blocks on top of QR codes. What I would like to do is to have those blocks (or whatever 3D model) always stand upright in the world, independent of the target's *or the camera's* (smartphone) position, and then also rotate at a constant pace around that axis.

What I have done is passed the device's accelerometer readings through a low pass filter, which gives me a vector that points along gravity. I then normalize it and multiply by -1 to get a unit vector that always points up. This is done once per frame.

Where I run into a problem is what to do with this vector; so far I tried simply setting it to the model's transform.up in the Update function, which correctly makes the model always stand upright, but also prevents any kind of rotation I try to give the object with transform.Rotate.

Is there a correct way to set the model's Y-axis that will still allow it to rotate around said axis?

Answer (score 1):

I have an idea that could work. Create an `Empty` as a child of the QR code and add your blocks as children of your `Empty`. Now you can update your `Empty` every frame to stand upright and let the blocks inside rotate relative to their parent.

By separating those two actions to separate GameObjects you should be able to avoid the problem with one command overwriting the other.